# Updating an Android app with original keystore but different project

Tags: android, keystore

Recently my computer crashed and I was only able to recover the keystore and apk of one of my Android apps (already published). Would it be possible to make an update to this app by creating a new project (the original one was lost) and using the original keystore? If so, how? Otherwise, how would I be able to update the app without the original project?

Comment: I suppose you DO have source of the project somewhere ?

Comment: If you mean source code, no, unfortunately.

Comment: You have to keep package name and proper app version number. If you have keystore and `private key password` (Note: keystore password is not critically needed here), you can release an update, yes, but you have to rewrite your whole app from scratch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create new project with same package name
   2.Write your code from scratch
   3.Update correct version code
   4.Generate Release APK with your key store and remember to write its password when asked.
   5.You are good to update on play store.

Answer (score 0):

As long as application Id and certificate used to sing release APK matches already released binary, you can publish whatever you want.

BTW: `Keystore` is **container** for your `keys`. So if you just recovered `keystore` it does not automatically mean you recovered your `keys` (as you might have forgot key password).